# Are Jquery's prop and attr supposed to behave differently?

Tags: jquery

http://jsbin.com/uremuc/2/edit

If I'm choosing jquery 1.5.2 in jsBin  ,

running `.attr('tagName')` should return me undefined ( or something else but not the real result) since its not suppose to read the dom element as Prop does.

So why is it working ?
It doesnt suppose to be working...

Comment: Because you're using 1.5.2. Use 1.6 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, `selectedIndex`, `tagName`, `nodeName`, `nodeType`, `ownerDocument`, `defaultChecked`, and `defaultSelected` should be retrieved and set with the `.prop()` method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the `.attr()` method, but this was not within the scope of `attr`. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

[From jquery.com's `.prop()` page](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)